# Preventing csvkit from modifying dates/times?

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv, xlrd

I'm just trying out [csvkit](http://csvkit.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.1/index.html) for converting Excel to csv. However, it's not taking into account formatting on dates and times, and producing different results from Excel's own save-as-csv. For example, this is a row of a spreadsheet:

[image]

And this what Excel's save-as produces:

```
22/04/1959,Bar,F,01:32.00,01:23.00,00:59.00,00:47.23
```

The date has no special formatting, and the time is formatted as `[mm].ss.00`. However, this is `in2csv`'s version of the csv:

```
1959-04-22,Bar,F,0.00106481481481,0.000960648148148,0.00068287037037,0.000546643518519
```

which is of course of no use at all. Any ideas? There don't seem to be any command-line options for this - `no-inference` doesn't help. Thanks.

**EDIT**

Both `csvkit` ans `xlrd` do seem to take into account formatting, but they're not smart about it. A date of 21/02/1066 is passed though as the text string '21/02/1066' in both cases, but a date '22/04/1959' is turned into '21662.0' by `xlrd`, and `1959-04-22` by `csvkit`. Both of them just give up on small elapsed times and pass through the float representation. This is Ok if you know that the cell should contain an elapsed time, because you can just multiply by `24*60*60` to get the right answer.

I don't think `xlrd` would be much help here since its date tuple functions only handle seconds, and not centiseconds.

**EDIT 2**

Found out something interesting. I started with a base spreadsheet containing times. In one of them I formatted the times as `[m:]ss.00`, and in the other I formatted them as `[mm:]ss.00`. I then saved each as a `.xls` and a `.xlsx`, giving a total of 4 spreadsheets. Excel could convert all 4 to csv, and all the time text in the csv's appeared as originally written (ie. `0:21.0`, for example, for 0m 21.0s).

`in2csv` can't handle the two `.xls` versions at all; this time appears as `00:00:21`. It also can't handle the `[m:]ss.00` version of the `.xlsx` - conversion gives the catch-all 'index out of range' error. The only one of the 4 spreadsheets that `in2csv` can handle is the `.xlsx` one, with `[mm:]ss.00` formatting.

Comment: Also looking at the same issue. According to https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/pull/779 this should be fixed now, but I am still not able to use --format-date parameter in the version provided via pip. I reckon you might be able to solve this by installing directly from git.

Comment: Interesting - I'll try to give it a go over the next few days.

Answer (score 0):

The optional `-I` argument should be working to avoid this issue. When testing your sample data, I get what Excel's save-as produces.

Command:
`in2csv sample.csv -I > sample-output-i.csv`

Output:
`22/04/1959,Bar,F,01:32.00,01:23.00,00:59.00,00:47.23`

`-I, --no-inference` Disable type inference when parsing CSV input.

https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/scripts/in2csv.html